# Wordpress, Dropdown Selection Menu for Author Profile field

Tags: php, wordpress, author

Wordpress noob here, After searching for two days without any success!, i'm trying to display a difference color in the front end for each selected option from menu.
I used this code for creating menu inside users profile

```html
<table class="form-table">
<tr>
        <th><label for="dropdown">Job Stats</label></th>
        <td>
            <?php 
            //get dropdown saved value
            $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_job_stats', $user->ID ); //there was an extra ) here that was not needed 
            ?>
            <select name="user_job_stats" id="user_job_stats">
                <option class="available" value="available" <?php echo ($selected == "available")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Available</option>
                <option class="busy" value="busy" <?php echo ($selected == "busy")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Busy</option>
</select>
            <span class="description">Select Stats.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And i used this code for displaying them in the front end

```html
<div class="job-stats">
<?php if (!empty(get_the_author_meta('user_job_stats', $curauth->ID))) { ?>
        <dt><?php echo $curauth->user_job_stats; ?></dt>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is when users selected an option ex:Busy
I want to make the background color of the option " Busy" to be red IN FRONT END
And with option "Available" background color to be green IN FRONT END.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSS's pseudo class to style the relevant tags.

```
<style>
    .available:checked { background: green; }
    .busy:checked { background: red; }
</style>



<table class="form-table">
<tr>
        <th><label for="dropdown">Job Stats</label></th>
        <td>
            <?php 
            //get dropdown saved value
            $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_job_stats', $user->ID ); //there was an extra ) here that was not needed 
            ?>
            <select name="user_job_stats" id="user_job_stats">
                <option class="available" value="available" <?php echo ($selected == "available")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Available</option>
                <option class="busy" value="busy" <?php echo ($selected == "busy")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Busy</option>
</select>
            <span class="description">Select Stats.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and for the front-end:

```
<style>
dt.available { background: green; }
dt.busy { background: red; }
</style>
<div class="job-stats">
<?php if (!empty(get_the_author_meta('user_job_stats', $curauth->ID))) { ?>
        <dt class="<?php echo $curauth->user_job_stats ?>"><?php echo $curauth->user_job_stats; ?></dt>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this css's working with backend! how can i figure out for the front end?

Comment: @AdhamMohamed i've updated the answer above. the CSS does appear in the front-end, in the HTML code next to your form

Comment: Thanks again @Matthew Knight not work with me, still work in the backend not front end.

Comment: @AdhamMohamed i'm not clear on what you mean 'work in the backend'?

Comment: backend = wp admin area , your code working +1 in the backend of the original menu when users select an option, but i need to figure it out in the frontend.

Comment: @AdhamMohamed oh i see - same technique, add a class to the <dt> tag, and then style it in the same way. answer updated. hth.